# Bootstrap push pull over multiple cols

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

On website I have something that looks like this

```
----------------------------------
| Image 1  | Image 2  | Image 3  |
----------------------------------
| Text 1   | Text 2   | Text 3   |
----------------------------------
```

On smaller devices I want this

```
----------------------
| Image 1  | Text 1  |
----------------------
| Image 2  | Text 2  |
----------------------
| Image 3  | Text 3  |
----------------------
```

On mobile I want this

```
-----------
| Image 1 |
-----------
| Text 1  | 
-----------
| Image 2 | 
-----------
| Text 2  | 
-----------
| Image 3 | 
-----------
| Text 3  | 
-----------
```

Evidently this will cause block to be pushed/pulled multiple times. Bootstrap doesn't seem to demonstrate how to do this.

This is the code that I have so far without the push/pulls:

```
                            <div id="services" class="col-sm-12">
                                <div id="services-img" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                        <img>IMG 1 HERE</img>                           
                                </div>
                                <div id="services-img" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                        <img>IMG 2 HERE</img>                           
                                </div>
                                <div id="services-img" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                        <img>IMG 3 HERE</img>                           
                                </div>
                                <div id="services-text" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                        <p>TEXT 1 HERE</p>                          
                                </div>
                                <div id="services-text" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                        <p>TEXT 2 HERE</p>                          
                                </div>
                                <div id="services-text" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                        <p>TEXT 3 HERE</p>                          
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the whole thing in `<div class="container">` and Change your first `<div id="services" class="col-sm-12">` to `<div id="services" class="row">`

Working example http://www.codeply.com/go/6x2iKhjcXj

BTW - you cannot have elements with the same id like `service-img`

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/fopdasqo/1/

No pull or push required :)

```
<div id="services" class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div id="services-img" class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
            <img>IMG 1 HERE</img>                           
        </div>
        <div id="services-text" class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
            <p>TEXT 1 HERE</p>                          
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div id="services-img" class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
            <img>IMG 2 HERE</img>                           
        </div>
        <div id="services-text" class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
            <p>TEXT 2 HERE</p>                          
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div id="services-img" class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
            <img>IMG 3 HERE</img>                           
        </div>
        <div id="services-text" class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
            <p>TEXT 3 HERE</p>                          
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Btw, I'm using "xs", "sm" and "md" since you mentioned mobile and tablet. "lg" will read from "md" automatically. If you want to move the media query one breakpoint larger, just replace all "xs" for "sm", "sm" for "md" and "md" for "lg".

If you want to test the DEMO full screen go here: https://jsfiddle.net/fopdasqo/1/embedded/result/